Cyclic relation
According to cyclic relation in calculus, we have $ \frac{\partial x}{ \partial z} * \frac{\partial z}{ \partial x}=1 $, which makes sense as it resembles $\frac{a}{b}* \frac{b}{a}=1$.
Then for three variables we have $\frac{\partial x}{ \partial y} * \frac{\partial y}{ \partial z}*\frac{\partial z}{ \partial x}=-1$. How can we explain this conceptually? why the relation for three variables is not equal to 1? (I have read the proof in textbooks, however, I am unable to find a conceptual or geometrical explanation for this).

@Gwen I prefer a geometrical explanation. However, I do not know the proof you mentioned. Can you please explain?

Typing here in the replies would be a bit problematic. Can I write it as an answer?

@Gwen yes plaese

Have you checked for posts about this identical question? I have answered several before.

@TedShifrin No, I was unable to find similar questions.

Here and here are two such posts. The thermodynamics notation is pretty much essential. The geometric interpretation quite simply comes by relating this all to implicit differentiation.

@TedShifrin geometrical explanation is exatly what I am after. Could you please elaborate?

There is not a simple geometric derivation of this fact. I will slightly reshape the discussion I wrote in the posts I already linked to you. The key idea is the implicit differentiation formula that introduces a negative sign: If $f(x,y)=c$ defines $y$ locally as a function $\phi$ of $x$, then
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}.$$
You can think of this geometrically in terms of the tangent line to $y=\phi(x)$ at $(a,b)$. Working with linear approximation along that graph, we have
$$0=\Delta f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)\Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)\Delta y,$$ and so, indeed,
$$\phi'(a) \approx \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)}.$$
Now, consider a level surface of a function of three variables. We start with $f(x,y,z) = c$ and assume this (locally) defines each of the variables as a differentiable function of the remaining two. It will now be important for clarity to introduce the notation — common in thermodynamics — of indicating with a subscript what variable is held fixed when we compute a partial derivative. From the two-variable formula I derived above, we get
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y &= -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}, \\
\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z &= -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}, \\
\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x &= -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}.
\end{align*}
Multiplying the three together, we get the result you want. Not very geometric, but it's all about implicit differentiation and tangent lines (planes).
I will remark that with partial derivatives it is generally false that
$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \dfrac 1{\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial z}}$. For example: Consider cartesian and polar coordinates, with
$$x=r\cos\theta,\ y=r\sin\theta \qquad\text{and}\qquad r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \ \theta = \arctan(y/x).$$
Then $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\theta} = -r\sin\theta = -y$, whereas $\dfrac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} = -\dfrac y{x^2+y^2}$. However, it is true, as you can check, that $\left(\dfrac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\right)_y = \dfrac 1{\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}\right)_y}$.

Thanks Ted, it is very clear now. Also, especially thanks for the point you made at the end of your answer, I had misunderstood the concept and now it makes a lot of sense.

This is not a geometric proof. As you have asked to show it,
We assume that $z(x,y)$ is differentiable and injective
$$dx=\bigg(\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial y}\bigg)dy + \bigg(\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial z}\bigg)dz$$
Similarly
$$dy=\bigg(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial x}\bigg)dx + \bigg(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial z}\bigg)dz$$
Substituting $dy$ in $dx$ gives
$$dx=\bigg(\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial y}\bigg)\bigg[\bigg(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial x}\bigg)dx + \bigg(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial z}\bigg)dz\bigg] + \bigg(\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial z}\bigg)dz$$
You can clearly see that using the cyclic relation you mentioned above, which also made sense for you, coefficient of $dx$ is $1$ in both sides of the equation. Thus
$$\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial z}\bigg)dz+\bigg(\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial z}\bigg)dz=0$$
Assuming $dz≠0$,
$$\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial z}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial z}\bigg)=0$$
$$\implies\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial z}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial x}\bigg)=-1$$

What is the codomain of $z$? If $\mathbb{R}$, then how can $z$ be simultaneously differentiable and injective?

@Tom I think I have a problem in my concept. We have started pd this year only. I thought if a function is differentiable, it should be bijective, and if it's bijective then it's injective. Maybe I am wrong. It will be really helpful if you explain my mistake
